# Is there a way to create contents of the schema into a Table in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, schema

Is there a way to create the contents of the BigQuery schema into a Table?
I don't want to create a table from the schema instead I want to move the contents of the schema into a BigQuery Table. I couldn't find any trivial method to do this.
Currently I download the table schema as JSON and then create a new table from it

Comment: You can select from the table into a destination Table with limit 0. If this doesn't help please provide code example and expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me!

```
SELECT *
  FROM
mydataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS
```